Provide async mixin variable to children
I'm trying to provide a value from an mixin that needs to get fetched first.
It seems that the provide is synchronous because the provided key is an empty observer at the time the children is created. I dont know how to make sure the children has the config data at its creation time.
Note I'm using Vue 2.7
I've already researched quite a bit but i haven't found a solution or a question with a similar problem.

Vue docs
( i also tried it with computed() as injected value but that changes nothing )

Here is an basic example:
App.vue
<script>
    import { configMixin } from '@/mixins/configMixin'
  import Child from './Child.vue'
  
  export default {
    mixins: ['configMixin'],
    components: [Child],
    async created() {
      await this.initConfig()
    },
    provide() {
      return {
        config: this.config
      }
    }
  }
</script>

<template>
    <div>
    <Child />
  </div>
</template>

configMixin.js
import { fetchMixin } from '@/mixins/fetchMixin';

export const configMixin = {
  mixins: [fetchMixin],
  data() {
    return {
      config: {},
      unwatchConfig: null
    };
  },

  beforeDestroy() {
    // Clean up the watcher when the component is destroyed
    if (this.unwatchConfig) {
      this.unwatchConfig(); // This un-watches the watcher
    }
  },

  methods: {
    async initConfig() {
      try {
        this.config = await this.fetch('api/config');
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Failed to fetch config:', error);
      } finally {
        this.setupConfigWatcher(); // Setup the watcher after fetching
      }
    },

    setupConfigWatcher() {
      this.unwatchConfig = this.$watch(
        'config',
        (newValue) => {
          this.saveConfig();
        },
        { deep: true }
      );
    },

    async saveConfig() {
      try {
        await this.fetch('api/config', {
          method: 'POST',
          body: this.config
        });
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Failed to save config:', error);
      }
    }
  }
};


Child.vue
<script>
  export default {
    inject: ['config'],
    created() {
      console.log(this.config)
      this.config.message = 'Hello World'
    }
  }
</script>

<template>
    <div>
    Child
  </div>
</template>


" i also tried it with computed() " - what did you try?

like it was in the docs for the options api -> that would be in my case provide() { return { config: computed(() => this.config) } }

You may have problems with other children reacting to this.config.message = because computed reactivity is shallow. And you will universally have problem in vue 2 because it's config: {} with no message. You'd need Vue.set for it. And it's generally a bad practice to mutate injected values in a child any way. I'd suggest to inject updateConfig(val) that will do either deepMerge(this.config, val) with config: { message: null } initial value, or this.config = deepClone(this.config, val), it will cause less problems with v2 reactivity

understandable, what would the appropriate way be then? A state managment like vuex?
I basically want to save as much redundant code as possible and make it very easy to change values inside it.
i did a simlar thing with a mixin and importing it in every component and using an init method but that leads to unnecessary requests to the backend and is kinda annoying initializing it in every component.

provide/inject object itself is a global store. It's currently limited to the use in components, while vuex isn't. Pinia is an up-to-date alternative that is focused on granular stores. It would be store = reactive({ config: { message: null }, update(val) { deepMerge(store.config, val) }. Don't forget to define the whole initial data structure for proper reactivity in V2. You can import it directly in non-comp modules or pass through provide/inject. See https://vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/state-management#simple-state-management-with-reactivity-api

config property should be reactive.
You can find an example here with ref() here: https://vuejs.org/guide/components/provide-inject#working-with-reactivity
In your case, you should use reactive(): https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/reactivity-fundamentals.html#reactive
